# Switch from MAMP to MAMP Pro, can't start mysql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, mamp, mamp-pro

I was using MAMP successfully, then once I needed to have more than one local dev environment, I purchased and downloaded MAMP Pro.  Now, mysql won't start in MAMP Pro, but still works correctly in MAMP.

Here is the mysql error log:

```
160804 16:21:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
160804 16:21:27 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
160804 16:21:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
160804 16:21:27 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB:     The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file ./ibdata1
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
160804 16:21:27 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
160804 16:21:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160804 16:21:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160804 16:21:27 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160804 16:21:27 [ERROR] Aborting

160804 16:21:27 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160804 16:21:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled MAMP and MAMP Pro using the uninstaller found in MAMP Pro.  I removed all files by dragging the apps into the trash and emptied the trash.  I reinstalled a new MAMP Pro and mysql is working as expected.